# Python socket: UDP Response not being received after broadcast

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

Using Python's socket library, I'm attempting to send a UDP broadcast packet to the network, then receive a UDP response. I am using Windows 7, Python 3.5.2.

I've simplified the program to the following code in which there are two configurations:

- Configuration 1 is what I'm trying to implement, a broadcast message that is agnostic to the IP of the target and expects to receive a response from the target for identification. The response is not received in this configuration.
- Configuration 2 is what I've found works in debugging, in which a message is sent directly to the target and the response is received. This isn't terribly useful as I need to know the IP of the target, but it demonstrates that the code snippet can send and receive were it not for the address.

```py
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

packet = b'\x00\x01\x00\x10'

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) # Interet, UDP

sock.bind(('192.168.1.15', 1001))  # IP of local PC. Must bind to use the correct interface as multiple interfaces are present.

# CONFIGURATION 1: BROADCAST - ONLY TRANSMITTED PACKET IS RECEIVED
sock.sendto(packet, ('192.168.1.255', 1001)) # Broadcast on local interface
# CONFIGURATION 2: DIRECT TO TARGET - RESPONSE IS RECEIVED
sock.sendto(packet, ('192.168.1.70', 1001)) # Direct to target

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(str(addr) + ': ' + str(data))
```

In Configuration 1, Wireshark indicates that a UDP request of 4 bytes is sent on port 1001 from 192.168.1.15 to 192.168.1.255, and a response is generated by the target of 30 bytes on port 1001 from 192.168.1.70 (the IP of the target) to 192.168.1.15 (the IP of the PC running the script). The script does not receive this response, though, and instead only prints what it requested:
`('192.168.1.15', 1001): b'\x00\x01\x00\x10'`

In Configuraton 2, Wireshark indicates that a UDP request of 4 bytes is sent on port 1001 from 192.168.1.15 to 192.168.1.70 (the IP of the target), and a response is generated by the target of 30 bytes on port 1001 from 192.168.1.70 to 192.168.1.15 (the IP of the PC running the script). The script does receive this response, and prints it: 
`('192.168.1.70', 1001): b'\x00\x02ABCDEFGH\x00ZYXWV\x000\x00ZYXWV\x00ABC\x00\x10'`

I have tried setting the SO_BROADCAST option `setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)`, but observed the same result.

I have tried setting the SO_REUSEADDR option `setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`, but observed the same result.

What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do not misuse broadcast for that. Use multicast, which is designed for such things. Broadcast interrupts _every_ host on the LAN, but multicast only interrupts those listening to the specific multicast group.

Comment: A great point, but unfortunately I'm trying to comply with ARINC 615A, and that's the way the spec is defined: "The initiator or Data loader sends a broadcast message requesting a response from all FIND hosts on the network, and then waits for responses. The initiator allows a 3-second window for responses. All valid responses are registered as targets for possible loading activity. When the 3 seconds window expires, the registration process is closed."

Comment: Well, many companies now will not approve applications that misuse broadcast in such a way, and the application could not be ported to IPv6 (also becoming a big requirement) because IPv6 does not have broadcast (the IETF saw how it was being misused, and decided to eliminate it in favor of multicast).

Comment: Hmm. This is running on a local aircraft network. I dug into the 615A specification and found "Destination IP address should be a unicast, multicast, or a broadcast IP address (full broadcast i.e., 255.255.255.255 or class-relevant broadcast e.g., 220.130.48.255 for a class C)." I changed my code to implement a multicast scheme (per the example here: https://pymotw.com/2/socket/multicast.html), but setting the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP parameter fails for my address in the 192.168.1.XX region as it's outside 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255. Unfortunately, I can't change the target IP. Thoughts?

Comment: The multicast group is not really an IP address. You need to know which multicast group to which the devices are subscribing. It may be a protocol specific multicast group that has been registered with IANA, or it may be on chosen in the Organization-Local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`). This has nothing to do with the IP address assigned to the interface. Think of it as a broadcast group to which the devices subscribe. You wouldn't set the IP address on an interface to a broadcast address, neither do you set the interface address to the multicast group.